# get value of body onload javascript with PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, phantomjs

Is there a solution to get the "*foo bar*" in JS (with jQuery ?) in this code ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body role="application" onload="foo bar">
    <div>...</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'am using [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) in my script.

EDIT: "*foo bar*" is an **example**. It's juste the value I would get.

EDIT 2: my code (wich don't work) is http://paste.awesom.eu/nca&ln.

EDIT 3: **PROBLEM(S) AND SOLUTION**

After many hours I find many problems and solutions.

First, the website is only accesible in **https** and I can't include jQuery file from non https url. That's why I have include the jQuery file from the website.

I have debug this with this code :

```
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
};
```

Then, I need to change my user agent because the website has a whitelist.

```
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0';
```

Finaly the code is:

```
page.open(url, function(status) {
    if ( status === "success" ) {
        page.includeJs(url_js_file, function() {
            page.evaluate(function() {
                console.log("> " + $("body").attr("onload"));
            });
            phantom.exit();
        });
    }
});
```

Thank you for comments and anwers.

Comment: No there is not, as this makes no sense at all.

Comment: `onload` should normally contain JavaScript that will be executed when the body loads.

Comment: This code will result in a javascript error shown in the console of your webbrowser. The `onload` attribute should contain valid javascript code that the browser will attempt to execute. So attempting to get something after a javascript occurred is like asking how to drive my car after my car has lost its wheels. You know, kinda impossible.

Comment: @adeneo I need this because it contains a value I need get.

Comment: @Jason I not thaht, thanks. DarinDimitrov it's just an example.

Comment: @gustavi what do you mean it contains a value you need to get? That's not really the best place to store user defined values. For that HTML5 defines `data-` attributes.

Comment: @Jason Yes I know but I haven't write the website where I need get this value. Otherwise it would not be like that. This is not the problem here.

Comment: Is this wht u want!? onload="some_func('foo', 'bar')"

Comment: @Murali No, I want a var with the value of the _onload_. Like the value of _id_, _class_ ...

Comment: @gustavi I think we all got hung up on the Javascript bit and didn't see the PhantomJS bit. That might be useful info for the title since it makes a huge difference in what you're actually asking. I think my answer below should cover it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are not returning your variable out of evaluate.
To do that you must

```
var bodyonload = page.evaluate(function (s) {
    return document.body.getAttribute('onload');
}, 'bodyonload');
```

You were very close to having it.

Here is your code where it returns an object rather than just a variable. I figured it could be useful.

```
page.open(url, function (status) {
  if (status !== 'success') {
    console.log('FAILED: ' + status);
  } else {
    var result = page.evaluate(function (s) {
      var result = {
        bodyOnLoad: document.body.getAttribute('onload'),
        documentTitle: document.title
      };
      return result;
    }, 'result');
    console.log(result.bodyOnLoad);
  }
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Hope that helps

---

Edit:
Looked at it some more and perhaps there is a problem with your reference to jquery in `page.injectJs()`, is jquery in the same directory?

Comment: Tank you for your answer, that's help me to find the problem !

Answer (score 0):

There should be no space between function name, It should like `<body role="application" onload="foobar()">` instead of `<body role="application" onload="foo bar">`

In between HTML head tag,

```
 <script>
   function foobar(){
            alert('Am loaded');
   }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
document.body.getAttribute("onload")
```

Comment: Thank you but this not work :/. `return document.body.getAttribute("onload")` return nothing.

Comment: It does here on Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/gvhfw/ What browser are you testing with?

Comment: Ooops sorry. I should have paid more attention to your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the actual, literal **value** of `onload`, use `$('body').attr('onload')`. This will return the [value of any attribute](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), for any element (assuming jQuery is being used). If not using jQuery, `document.body.getAttribute("onload")` should do the trick.

Keep in mind that since PhantomJS technically runs *outside* of the targeted page's DOM, you need to [wrap any DOM scripts](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Page-Automation#dom-manipulation) in `page.evaluate`:

```
page.evaluate(function () {
    // put your $('body').attr('onload') bit here.
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that jQuery is being injected properly? Try using the `getAttribute` method.

Comment: @gustavi: parsed your code again, here's what I found: it looks like a problem with your use of `return`. Try setting the value of a variable directly. Take a look at [this code](http://paste.awesom.eu/ach) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me for returning the value in `onload`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body role="application" onload="foo bar">
    <div>...</div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        console.log($("body").attr("onload"));
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```